# Problemas para devolver un array ordenado en javascript sin ecmascript 6 etc

Tags: javascript

**Tengo dos arrays de números quisiera retornar un array con los elementos de esos dos arrays y que estén ordenados, sin importar el proceso, sea que sea un nuevo array ó se trabaje sobre lo/s mismo/s. Quiero construir sin usar atajos como concat(), sort() y esos que se los hace en una linea. Quisiera entender la logica. Estoy trabajando en Javascript**

1. `a = [1,3,4]`;
2. `b = [2,4,6]`;
3. `c = []`;

Mi código era hacer una función(a,b,c) y ponerle dentro un " for " que vaya recorriendo " i <= a.length " y adentro preguntar si " a[i] " es menor a " b[i] " entonces que lo pushee a la variable venida por parametro " c ".
Pero todo ésto me devuelve un array con dos números [2, 5]. Ni sé siquiera porque no iteró sobre el segundo el "3" de la variable "a" y el "4" de la variable "b". No entiendo cómo plantearlo ni menos como solucionar eso.
Inicialmente quería hacerlo con un `while` pero nose cómo condicionarlo. Osea nose como plantearlo para que según una condición me itere ya que `while(a.length){ if(a[0] < b[0]{ c.push(a[0]) } if( a[0]>b[0]){ c.push(b[0])} }` me hará un bucle infinito.
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso como no quieres usar `ES6` deberás entonces usar varios ciclos anidados para tu propósito.

Al inicio había optado por usar también un ciclo `while` pero realmente me di cuenta de que no era necesario, por lo que procedí directamente a llenar el array de una manera sencilla, y simplemente desempaquetando o aplanando luego el array usando la función `flat` que hace parte del estándar de `ES5`, el método de ordenamiento usado en este caso fue el método de ordenamiento de la burbuja.

Método el cual comprueba el primer elemento de la lista con todos los siguientes y en caso de encontrar uno que no cumpla con la secuencia lo cambia de puesto con el otro, esto se repite las veces que sea necesario, y puede ser usado tanto para ordenamiento de mayor a menor como ordenamiento de menor a mayor, aquí el código allegado:

```js
var a = [1, 3, 4];
var b = [2, 4, 6];

function bubbleSort(a, b){
  var c = [a, b].flat();

  for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < c.length - 1 - i; j++){
      if(c[j] > c[j + 1]){
        var swap = c[j];
        c[j] = c[j + 1];
        c[j + 1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return c;

}

console.log(bubbleSort(a, b));
```

En internet puedes encontrar información mas relevante acerca de este método de ordenamiento el cual por cierto aunque puede no ser el mas eficiente es uno de los mas sencillos de implementar.

Pero de manera resumida la idea del ordenamiento de burbuja es siempre ir comparando el elemento actual con el elemento anterior de la lista hasta llegar al ultimo, luego repetir esto pero comenzando desde el primer elemento de la lista hasta el ultimo, luego el segundo hasta el ultimo y así sucesivamente.

con esto te das una idea del porque no es un algoritmo especialmente eficiente... pues mientras mas elementos por ordenar haya mas demorara en terminar el bubble sort.

donde requerimos dos ciclos anidados:

```
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < c.length - 1 - i; j++){
```

El primero iterara sobre todo el arreglo, mientras que el segundo iterara `x` veces desde el punto de ordenacion, es decir, supongamos tenemos esto:

```
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5];
```

`j` en este caso llegaria a valer un máximo de 2, pues los 2 primeros elementos ya se encuentran ordenados, por lo que no se recorren de acuerdo a la condición `c.length - 1 - i`.

Mas adelante tenemos la condicion de cambio:

```
if(c[j] > c[j + 1]){
```

En la que dependiendo de si queremos un ordenamiento de mayor a menor o de menor a mayor debemos cambiar el símbolo `>` a `<` o viceversa, en este caso se trata de un ordenamiento de menor a mayor, ya que haremos el cambio en caso de que el elemento actual (`c[j]`) sea mayor al elemento siguiente (`c[j + 1]`).

Al final vemos esta parte:

```
var swap = c[j];
c[j] = c[j + 1];
c[j + 1] = swap;
```

La variable `swap` se encarga en este caso de prealmacenar un valor antes de cambiarlo para **NO** perderlo, ya que si lo cambiamos sin mas vamos a tener problemas lógicos y el ordenamiento no sera correcto.

por ultimo hacemos el cambio:

```
c[j] = c[j + 1];
c[j + 1] = swap;
```

que se traduce a algo así:

```
c = [4, 3];
c = [3, 4];
```

Dando fin a la explicación del bubble sort.

Algo mas que me gustaria aclarar es el problema de tu caso, el caso que describes, en este caso era el siguiente según tus palabras:

> preguntar si " a[i] " es menor a " b[i] " entonces que lo pushee a la
> variable venida por parametro " c "

Entonces esto se traduce en codigo a:

```
if(a[i] < b[i]){
  c.push(????);
}
```

El problema de esta condición es que **NO** puedes dejar por fuera ningún elemento, y ahí estas literalmente diciéndole al programa que te deje por fuera elementos que no cumplan tu condición, que naturalmente esto se traduciría a que no todo el arreglo se llena y por lo tanto el ordenamiento no es correcto.

Comment: En breves edito la respuesta y coloco mas detalles, siento que esta algo pobre la respuesta, pero me ocupe un poco, luego la edito y explico mas a detalle el bubble sort.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, @Riven, incluso antes de la edición. Quizá solo faltó evitar el uso de `flat()`, pero eso no te quita el +1.

Comment: @Triby.no comprendí tu algoritmo. Sin duda los dos tienen +1

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @Riven es excelente, creo que solo debería evitar el uso de `.flat()` y unir los arreglos por medio de otra función. Dejo este ejemplo solo para complementar.

```js
var a = [1, 3, 4, [7, 9, [10, 12]]];
var b = [2, 4, 6];

/*
 * Unir arreglos y elementos en un solo arreglo
 * @param array acum     Elemento acumulador con valor inicial
 * @param mixed          Uno o más elementos o arreglos para unir
 */
function arrayFlat() {
    // Valor inicial
    var acum = arguments[0];
    // Recorrer argumentos para agregar al arreglo
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        // Si es un arreglo
        if(Array.isArray(arguments[i])) {
            // Recorrer para agregar
            for(var x = 0; x < arguments[i].length; x++) {
                // Si es un arreglo interno
                if(Array.isArray(arguments[i][x])) {
                    // Ejecutar de forma recursiva
                    acum = arrayFlat(acum, arguments[i][x]);
                } else {
                    // Si es elemento, solo se agrega
                    acum.push(arguments[i][x]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Si es elemento, solo se agrega
            acum.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    return acum;
}

console.log(arrayFlat([], a, b, 20));
```

Seguramente habrá mejores formas de lograrlo, esto fue lo que salió "al vuelo".

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte Triby, tambien esta Excelente!, habia de hecho realizado el algoritmo sin usar `flat` usando un ciclo while, pero considere que para algo tan sencillo como lo es aplanar un array no se necesitaria una explicacion, por lo tanto quice saltarme un poco de codigo usando `flat`, igual tu respuesta complementa muy muy bien un reemplazo de flat, excelente! +1